# How to get an automatic effect of rosace in css ?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am making a website and there is an effect which I have putted on a circle. The circle automaticlly opens on mouse hover and then it get close when the mouse get away. I just want to make it automatic . mens it should open and close automaticlly. Here is my css code for the circle .
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
   <h1>TRANCE-2014</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .circle {
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-radius: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 15em;
      height: 15em;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .circle h1 {
      color: rgba(189, 185, 199, 0);
      font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 1.6em;
      line-height: 8.2em;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
      transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }
  .circle:before, .circle:after {
      border-radius: 100%;
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      box-shadow: inset 10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset -10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 -10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2);
      -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
      -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
      -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
      transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
  }
  .circle:after {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .circle:hover:before, .circle:hover:after {
      box-shadow: inset 0.86em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 0.86em 0 rgba(252, 150, 0, 0.5), inset -0.86em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -0.86em 0 rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .circle:hover > h1 {
      color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 1);
  }
```

Comment: calling code is just div tag with class circle and the cirlcle class is defined in css code .

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by *automatic*? When should the animation start? (By the way, very nice job!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RR7pu/2/) ?

If so you have to use the `@keyframes` element of CSS. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/@keyframes) or on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
.circle h1 {
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 8.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-animation: showText 2s infinite; /* Safari/Chrome 4+ */
    -moz-animation: showText 2s infinite;    /* Firefox 5+ */
    -o-animation: showText 2s infinite;      /* Opera 12+ */     
    animation: showText 2s infinite;         /* IE 10+ */
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    /*
    ** -webkit-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
    ** -moz-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
    ** -ms-transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
    ** transition: color 0.8s ease-in-out;
    */
}
.circle:before, .circle:after {
    border-radius: 100%;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    -webkit-animation: moveCircle 2s infinite; /* Safari/Chrome 4+ */
    -moz-animation: moveCircle 2s infinite;    /* Firefox 5+ */
    -o-animation: moveCircle 2s infinite;      /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: moveCircle 2s infinite;         /* IE 10+ */

    /*
    ** -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
    ** -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
    ** -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
    ** transition: box-shadow 0.75s;
    */
}
.circle:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveCircle {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset -10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 -10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0.86em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 0.86em 0 rgba(252, 150, 0, 0.5), inset -0.86em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -0.86em 0 rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveCircle {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset -10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 -10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0.86em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 0.86em 0 rgba(252, 150, 0, 0.5), inset -0.86em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -0.86em 0 rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes moveCircle {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset -10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 -10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0.86em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 0.86em 0 rgba(252, 150, 0, 0.5), inset -0.86em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -0.86em 0 rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
    }
}
@keyframes moveCircle {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset -10.6em 0 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2), inset 0 -10.6em 0 rgba(30, 140, 209, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0.86em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 0.86em 0 rgba(252, 150, 0, 0.5), inset -0.86em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -0.86em 0 rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showText {
    0% {
        color: rgba(189, 185, 199, 0);
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes showText {
    0% {
        color: rgba(189, 185, 199, 0);
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 1);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes showText {
    0% {
        color: rgba(189, 185, 199, 0);
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 1);
    }
}
@keyframes showText {
    0% {
        color: rgba(189, 185, 199, 0);
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: bro u just solved my problem. but i was wondering if u could manage to get it closed in the same way it opens

Comment: @user3448962 just use the keyword `alternate` . [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6G4GW/)

Comment: may u plz koin me on fb or google + i relly need someone to solve my small queries...

Comment: hey how can i put an image in it . i m using img rc tag but image is not coming . @alosdg